# How to improve DOM render time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have quite complex Angular application that is using `ui-router` to switch views. We recently noticed that switching views can produce from 300ms to 1500ms lag.

We eliminated the following possible causes:

- AJAX calls - data is already loaded
- async html template fetching - we are using html2js
- complex logic on $digest - profiler didn't show any heavy functions called
- using one-time bindings instead of two-way bindings have almost no effect on the initial render

We figured out that the lag will most likely be caused by rendering too many DOM elements on the page.

Apart of the obvious solution - reducing DOM elements rendered (which is not easy to do with keeping the same functionality) what can we do to improve DOM rendering speed?

Our views are mostly composed by many small directives. Is there a way to render directives and DOM elements asynchronously (without blocking the UI) or to display a spinner while DOM tree of a directive/view is rendering?

Comment: The DOM is rendered by the browser, not your code, so your influence on that process is limited. But it should be possible to first display a simple DOM with a spinner and then initialize the rendering.

Comment: I have run into lag times often when building large complex UI's with lots of DOM elements (specifically inputs, or stuff like select2).  You should test what the rendering difference is between Chrome and IE11.  Chrome renders elements much faster than IE (but may still be slow) so if there is a big difference between the two you can pin point that rendering is the issue.  If that is the issue you can build code to prevent offscreen elements from rendering until they are in view with javascript.  If it seems that is the case let me know and I have some code I can post to an anwer

Comment: It would help if you would try getting some data with (for example) open page in chrome -> more tools -> Developer tools -> Timeline & refresh page

Comment: "*We figured out that the lag will most likely be caused*", can you explain **how**?

Comment: You could consider checking for superfluous $watch mechanics; but I'm assuming you already are keeping an eye on that if you mentioned that reducing two-way binding to one-way has little effect. A second thing you could consider is breaking up the rendering -- if you page involves scrolling, don't rending things that aren't going to be visible to begin with. Only create those as the user starts to scroll or makes tabs visible. Or only render the content of initially invisible tabs after finishing with the content that is immediately visible.

Comment: What about using a profiler? And check the most consuming time functions.

Comment: btw, my approach was like this. 1. combine all api call to one at server side and inject that json directly to html. 2. wrote my own router based on ng-route 3. wrote my own renderer with zero binding. 4. wrote my own server side rendering with my own redender and router. 5. forked angular to my own, and tune them to my taste.

Comment: @YOU 1) This will really not help much if the api calls take some time to load and defeats advantages of asynchronous loading. I'd like to see more information about your ng-route, renderer and angular forks though :)

Comment: @PetrPeller, this is my renderer - https://github.com/S-YOU/doTA, my router - https://github.com/S-YOU/doTA.Router, and my angular fork - https://github.com/S-YOU/angular-defer

Comment: And this is the company's website I work for and, I use all those in - https://www.giveucar.com/ . Note that the website is hosted in-house in Japan, so it will take a some time to resolve DNS.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ng-hide/ng-show one way to make your load time faster is to swich to ng-if exclusively, that way those parts of the DOM only load if they're needed, reducing what's loaded to the page initially.

> ngIf differs from ngShow and ngHide in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property. A common case when this difference is significant is when using css selectors that rely on an element's position within the DOM, such as the :first-child or :last-child pseudo-classes.

[From Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: Thanks, we are already aware of this and using ngIf where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately rendering lots of DOM nodes is what has the biggest impact on rendering time.

Like the other answer suggest, not only using `ng-if` will append less element to the DOM, but also any directive or controllers attached to these elements won't be compiled, so huge boost in some cases.

Otherwise, you should focus on deciding whether you really need so many elements on the page laoded at once. Often, they are not all visible immediately. One very good mechanism for instance if the page is very tall or if you're using `ng-repeat` (world famous performance killer), is to use "infinite scrolling", which means you limit the amount of node displayed with `limitTo` in the case of `ng-repeat` for instance, and you extend this limit when the user scrolls down.

PS: Google Chrome (at least) is very good at profiling what causes the lag if you enable the Timeline from the dev console and stop it after the full loading.

PPS: One way to check that you don't have a very slow watcher is to run these lines from the developper console (replace body by whichever node has a scope)

```
var scope = $('body').scope();
console.time('100 apply');
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) scope.$apply();
console.timeEnd('100 apply');
```

This shoudn't take more than 100 - 300ms in case of a big application.